# using jquery ui datepicker and changing date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format

I can't change the date format.. about to tear my hair out. Searched the API and tried it all. Tried everything

## HTML

```
<body>
  <p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
  </p>
</body>
```

## jQuery

```
$(function () {
  $(".selector").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "calendar_icon120121018-7997-10s714y-0_original.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true
  });
});
```

Comment: code shows `dateformat` so you haven't explained what the issue is. Please be more specific and if problem relates to external data provide sample

Comment: Define dateFormat in `#datepicker`

Comment: i want the date to be = day month year, instead of the default = month, day, year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have copy-pasted this line from the API:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

`.selector` is a placeholder for the element you apply the datepicker to, in this case `#datepicker`. It's just an example, you have to modify it to fit into your own code.

Put the `dateFormat` option to the actual datepicker initializer, just like all the other options:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    showOn: "button",            
    buttonImage: "calendar_icon120121018-7997-10s714y-0_original.png",          
    buttonImageOnly: true    
});
```